# (angular 4) field touched functions after clicking on the form

Tags: angular, touch-event

I have a form:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)">
```

and I want to make a specific production after clicking on any element of the form eg.

```
<form [formGroup]="form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)" touched="func()">
```

How can this be done - and work?
I read about touched or dirty directive, but I don't know how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Hi below are the properties which you may implement not $touched

```
   "$error":{  },
   "$name":"myForm",
   "$dirty":false,
   "$pristine":true,
   "$valid":false,
   "$invalid":true,
   "$submitted":false
```

Comment: <form [formGroup]="form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)" dirty="func()">
??

Comment: no $dirty is boolean value and you have option to call form events such as $setDirty(); $setPristine(); $setUntouched(); $setSubmitted();

Comment: Actually, they are properties on input fields that you wanting to call function upon which is not possible

Comment: you may either call all the function in OnInit section to fulfil you needs insted of calling with touched or dirty

Comment: If i am able to answer please upvote and accept my answer

Comment: OnInt is only for start (?)
but I muss perform a function for every activity in the form

Comment: what is your requirement as might be some other ways to achieve this

Comment: how perform a function for every activity in the form?

Comment: I have to do the function when I'm active in the form

Comment: in that function call you are saving the data

Comment: is my hangout can you ping me ping me out ther

Comment: onSubmit I have func... and display info... info is active all time... it will be remove only when user click and edit filed in form... (not automaticly, not timer)

Comment: Give me a minute let me think about this and explore so that you are able to capture every keystroke in form

Answer (score 0):

touched is more a property which can be applied on an object attributte, to check if the input binded to this property get touched (modified) or not.

```
return true // if modified
return flase // if not
```

so I think it's not usefull in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to value changes also you may touched or dirty inside

```
 this.formname.valueChanges.subscribe(form => {
            sessionStorage.setItem('form', JSON.stringify(form));
          });
```

Below is the link for description

https://kfarst.github.io/angular/2016/12/12/subscribing-to-form-value-changes-in-angular-2/

Comment: I don't know how use sessionStorage in my case?

Comment: you may use implement your logic here what you are wanting to acheive on keystokes in my case i am saving using sessionStorage service

Comment: for all filed in form?

Comment: yes, you will get all form field values now please upvote and accept both answers